# Django 1.8 Conditional expression returns empty queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models that are something like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # fields...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    is_done = models.BooleanField()
    # more fields....
```

I would like to annotate `Foo` with a count of all the associated `Bar` objects for which `is_done` is true.

Unfortunately, I am trapped in Django 1.8, so `Count('bar', filter='bar__is_done`) is not an option for me.

So instead, I used a conditional aggregation:

```
Foo.objects.all().annotate(
    # other fields...
    done=Count(Case(
        When(bar__is_done=True, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

Unfortunately, this returns an empty queryset. Removing the conditional returns a queryset as normal, but the last annotation in particular seems to break the query.

What's wrong?

Comment: If you're stuck on a Django release that got its last security update over a year ago, you should be dealing with very low intranet traffic, and looping over `foo.bar_set.filter(is_done=True)` or something similar should not be an issue. If you're actually hosting this in a place that's accessible to the internet, this is definitely not the issue you should be addressing first.